# Context conflict error in Nuxt 3 with @sidebase/nuxt-auth and Histoire Vue

Tags: vuejs3, next-auth, nuxt3, nuxt-auth

I'm currently working on a Nuxt 3 project with Vue 3 and have integrated the **@sidebase/nuxt-auth** module along with Histoire Vue. However, when running yarn **story:dev**, I encounter the following error:

[Historie conflict error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r8n1P.jpg)

Configuration Files:

Here are the relevant parts of my **nuxt.config.ts**:

```js
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  modules: [
    '@nuxtjs/tailwindcss',
    'nuxt-icon', // Integration with Icon Module
    '@pinia/nuxt', // Integration with Pinia
    '@sidebase/nuxt-auth', // Integration with Auth Module
    '@nuxtjs/robots',
    'nuxt-viewport',
  ],

  css: ['@/assets/css/main.css', '@/assets/css/roboto.css', '@/assets/css/ubuntu.css'],

  runtimeConfig: {
    public: {
      API_BASE_URL: process.env.API_BASE_URL,
      STAGING_MODE: process.env.STAGING_MODE,
      GOOGLE_PLACES_API_KEY: process.env.GOOGLE_PLACES_API_KEY,
      GETITFRONTEND_URL:
        process.env.STAGING_MODE === 'true'
          ? 'https://staging.get.it'
          : process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
          ? 'https://www.get.it'
          : 'http://localhost:3000',
    },
  },

  // App configuration
  app: {
    // Head configuration
    head: {
      // HTML attributes
      htmlAttrs: {
        lang: 'en', // Set the default language to English
      },
      title: '@ Get.It',
    },
  },
});
```

And my **histoire.config.ts**:

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'histoire';
import { HstNuxt } from '@histoire/plugin-nuxt';
import { HstVue } from '@histoire/plugin-vue';

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [HstVue(), HstNuxt()],
});
```

This issue seems to be related to the @sidebase/nuxt-auth module. Interestingly, removing this module resolves the conflict, allowing Histoire Vue to work as expected. I've scoured online resources but couldn't find a similar case, prompting me to seek assistance here.

Has anyone faced a similar context conflict when using @sidebase/nuxt-auth and Histoire Vue in a Nuxt 3 project? Any insights or suggestions on resolving this issue would be highly appreciated.

Thank you for your assistance!